# How to apply PoS tags to a nested list in R across multiple rows?

Tags: r, nlp, tuples, text-mining, tagging

I am trying to apply PoS tagging in R to a column that contains a variable that was a sentence. This variable has been tokenised with all irrelavanices removed (punctuation, spaces, spelling etc)

Here are the first few rows of the data

| Row_id | no_punct |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [dec,brighton,hove,women,have,applied] |
| 2 | [jan,england,has,joined,tottenha,from,chelsea] |

My code so far looks like:

```
udmodel <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
udmodel <- udpipe_load_model(file = udmodel$file_model)

df$pos_tags <- udpipe_annotate(udmodel, 
                    df$no_punct_no_spaces)
```

However, the output is reading as 'NULL'. My desired output is to create a new tuples variable named 'pos_tags' that contains the word and the tag (i.e. "dec, N") across each row.

| Row_id | pos_tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [dec NN,brighton NN,hove NN,women NN,have AD,applied PN] |

Which package in R would you suggest to do this with?
And if you could provide a code example that'd be great.

Thank you

My code so far looks like:

```
udmodel <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
udmodel <- udpipe_load_model(file = udmodel$file_model)

df$pos_tags <- udpipe_annotate(udmodel, 
                    df$no_punct_no_spaces)
```

However, the output is reading as 'NULL'.